# Can't build has_many association with Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a `User` that `has_many` posts in Rails 4.1.6. Following the [Getting Started page for Factory Girl](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md), I have created these factories:

```
factory :post do
  skip_create
  title 'foo bar'
  user
end

factory :user do
  skip_create
  id 1
  username 'alice'

  factory :user_with_posts do
    skip_create

    transient do
      posts_count 5
    end

    after(:build) do |user, evaluator|
      build_list(:post, evaluator.posts_count, user: user)
    end
  end
end
```

But calling `build(:user_with_posts)` returns a `User` with an empty `posts` array. Calling `build_list(:post, 5, user: user)` (with a pre-built `User`) works.

What am I missing?

Also, is there a way to set a global `skip_create` so I don't have to set it on each factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and all according to all the docs I was reading, it should have been working. Here is what finally worked (adapted for your code):

change

```
build_list(:post, evaluator.posts_count, user: user)
```

to

```
user.posts = build_list(:post, evaluator.posts_count, user: user)
```

Let me know if that doesn't work, but that's what solved it for me.

Comment: Or, in your case, it might have to be user_with_posts.posts = build_list(:post, evaluator.posts_count, user: user)